# NamedParameterJdbcTemplate cannot execute insert into select

Tags: spring, jdbc, informix

I'm using informix and I'm trying to execute a simple query from java using spring. This is the query.

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT val1, val2, val3
FROM table2
WHERE condition
```

I've verified the query syntax and if execute it using a client, runs perfectly. But when it runs using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` throws syntax error and I don't know why. Somebody could explain me the reasons and a good way to solve my problem.

This is my java code.

```
String LOG_INFO = 
   "INSERT INTO table1 SELECT val1,  val2,  (SYSDATE - 5 UNITS HOUR),  val3 " +
   " FROM table2 " +
   " WHERE membership_nbr = :user_nbr_param";
String USER_NBR_PARAM = "user_nbr_param";

@Autowired
  private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public Integer logInfo(BigInteger userNbr) {
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue(USER_NBR_PARAM, userNbr);

    return jdbcTemplate.update(LOG_INFO, params);
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this by taking `Map` instead of `MapSqlParameterSource` :

```
public Integer logInfo(BigInteger userNbr) {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(USER_NBR_PARAM, userNbr);
    return jdbcTemplate.update(LOG_INFO, params);
}
```

Read this : [why we use MapSqlParameterSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742116/why-we-use-mapsqlparametersource) for more info.