# namedParameterJdbcTemplate update return 1 but data is not added to database POSTGRES SPRING-JDBC

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am new to backend development and currently i am facing an issue with adding data to my postgres db from spring DAO service using namedParameterJdbcTemplate.

```
public int addCompany(CompanyDto companyDto) throws DataAccessException {
        MapSqlParameterSource namedParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        namedParams.addValue("name", companyDto.getName());

        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(
            CompanyQueries.ADD_COMPANY,
            namedParams
    );
}
```

```
public class CompanyQueries {
    public static final String ADD_COMPANY = "INSERT INTO company (name) values (:name);";
}
```

But when i call the endpoint and the update in addCompany() is called it returns 1 , sequence for id of the table is incremented, no errors in db logs at all, I turned on csvlogs in postgresql.conf.

And the selects by namedParameterJdbcTemplate work correct.

POSTGRES VERSION 15
JAVA 17
SPRING 6
SPRING BOOT 3

When i run the query in datagrip console row is added.

Comment: May be it's similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331334/namedparameterjdbctemplate-cannot-execute-insert-into-select

Comment: It didn't help. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the transaction isn't being committed in the end.
How i came with solution.

1. Put the log level to debug in application.yml in spring.
2. saw a message stating that transaction is being rolled back because of dirty state.
3. found that i have copied datasource configs with auto-commit=false in application.yml.