# A way to update multiple records together?

Tags: spring, oracle, java-8, spring-jdbc, upsert

I am trying to see if there is a way to improve the way data is inserted and updated.

I am using ORACLE DB with JDBC.

The current way i'm doing is to update (e.g.)customer record by using a FOR loop after checking if `toUpdate` is `true` . An Example such as the sample code below, followed by calling an existing DAO `update()` to do so. But this would not allow for the UPSERT of multiple data together.

However, is there a better way to UPSERT multiple data together?

```
        if (toUpdate) {
            for (Customer customerRec : customerRecList) 
                customerRecDAO.update(customerRec);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using spring JDBC template ?

Comment: In Spring-boot with spring data jpa we have saveAll(). If spring JDBC go through https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use batching:

```java
public <T> int saveInBatch(List<T> records, String sql, Function<T, MapSqlParameterSource> paramFn){

try{
MapSqlParameterSource[] params = records.stream().map(paramFn).toArray(MapSqlParameterSource[]::new);
int rowCount = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, params);
return Arrays.stream(rowCount).sum();
}
catch(Exception e){
//exception handling 
}
}
```

`paramFn` is a lambda of function such that you can map records to their values. example could be

```
(record)->{
return new MapSqlParameterSource("username" ,username),Integer.class);//just example
}
```

[why we use MapSqlParameterSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742116/why-we-use-mapsqlparametersource)

You can call saveInBatch in such a way that you pass smaller batches or customized batches of records. Suppose you have a million records then you may want to update only 200-400 records at a time so you can do something like below:

```
private <T> int saveRecords(List<T> records, String sql, Function<T, MapSqlParameterSource> paramFn) throws Exception{

return Lists.partition(records, 300).stream().map(batch-> saveInBatch(batch, sql, paramFn)).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
}
```

`Note:` above is not well optimized or streams are not used to their best but this is a working code I tried ages back :).